# How can I sum rows in groups of three?

Tags: r, sum, row

I have this data and I want sum in groups of three the rows, 1-3,4-6,7-9,10-12. In my data frame I have 48 rows and 795 variables. Could you help me?

My data frame:

```
       X1       X2      X3      X4      X5      X6       X7     X8      X9     
1     0.00     0.00  136.29    0.00   60.52    0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00
2     0.00     0.00 4658.69    0.00    0.00 1749.50     0.00   0.00    0.00
3     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  125.86     0.00   0.00    0.00
4     0.00     0.00  119.34    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00
5     0.00     0.00 4674.16 2107.55    0.00    0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00
6     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 5689.40     0.00   0.00    0.00
7  4270.87     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 3275.74     0.00   0.00    0.00
8     0.00   455.04    0.00    0.00    0.00 1296.30     0.00   0.00    0.00
9     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 9887.52     0.00   0.00    0.00
10    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00
11    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00 2169.64    0.00     0.00   0.00  699.93
12    0.00 12524.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00
```

This is what I want:

```
       X1       X2      X3      X4      X5      X6       X7     X8      X9
1     0.00     0.00  ......
2     0.00     0.00  ......
3  4270.87   455.04  ......
4     0.00 12524.50  ......
```

Comment: See, also, `?rowsum` -- `rowsum(data, appropriate_grouping_vector)`

Comment: @alexis_laz nice one, so simple! `rowsum(df1, rep(1:4, each = 3))`, consider posting as an answer.

Comment: @alexis_laz - damn... I always forget `rowsum` - a much better solution than mine below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R solution using `filter` (that's `stats::filter` - which `dplyr` bulldozes if already loaded - beware):

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) filter(x, c(1,1,1), sides=1)[seq(3, nrow(df), 3)] ))
#       X1       X2      X3      X4      X5       X6 X7 X8     X9
#1    0.00     0.00 4794.98    0.00   60.52  1875.36  0  0   0.00
#2    0.00     0.00 4793.50 2107.55    0.00  5689.40  0  0   0.00
#3 4270.87   455.04    0.00    0.00    0.00 14459.56  0  0   0.00
#4    0.00 12524.50    0.00    0.00 2169.64     0.00  0  0 699.93
```

As @alexis_laz notes above `?rowsum` is probably preferable, as it was explicitly defined for this purpose, in the form:

```
rowsum(data, appropriate_grouping_vector)
```

So, something like:

```
rowsum(dat, (1:nrow(dat) - 1) %/% 3)
#       X1       X2      X3      X4      X5       X6 X7 X8     X9
#0    0.00     0.00 4794.98    0.00   60.52  1875.36  0  0   0.00
#1    0.00     0.00 4793.50 2107.55    0.00  5689.40  0  0   0.00
#2 4270.87   455.04    0.00    0.00    0.00 14459.56  0  0   0.00
#3    0.00 12524.50    0.00    0.00 2169.64     0.00  0  0 699.93
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below is a `dplyr` solution modified from its source ([Summing columns on every nth row of a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267398/summing-columns-on-every-nth-row-of-a-data-frame-in-r)).

It solves the problem by creating an index variable with which to group rows, and then takes rowsums of those subset rows. `n` can take any value, provided that `nrow(df)` is divisible by `n`.

```
df <- data.frame(runif(30), runif(30), runif(30))
library(plyr); library(dplyr)

n <- 3

df %>%
  group_by(indx = gl(ceiling(nrow(df)/n), n, nrow(df))) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

Split data on n rows, then sum:

```
# dummy data
df1 <- mtcars[1:12, 1:6]

# split sum combine 
t(sapply(split(df1, rep(1:4, each = 3)), colSums))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
df$group <- ceiling((1:nrow(df))/3)
aggregate(. ~ group, data = df, sum)[-1]

       X1       X2      X3      X4      X5       X6 X7 X8     X9
1    0.00     0.00 4794.98    0.00   60.52  1875.36  0  0   0.00
2    0.00     0.00 4793.50 2107.55    0.00  5689.40  0  0   0.00
3 4270.87   455.04    0.00    0.00    0.00 14459.56  0  0   0.00
4    0.00 12524.50    0.00    0.00 2169.64     0.00  0  0 699.93
```