# How to sum column data every nth row, including non numerical data in Rstudio

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame made of 420 rows and 37 columns from insect field sampling data. I am trying to sum column values every 5 rows so that every 5 rows becomes just 1. In addition I am trying to make the non numerical values in my dataframe($site, $date, $plot) "collapse" so they fit the single new row made of the sums I mentioned.

I have tried using advice from this thread:

[Summing columns on every nth row of a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267398/summing-columns-on-every-nth-row-of-a-data-frame-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Including using package dplyr's summarize_each function as well as gl and colSums that are part of data.table.

I have tried these on my whole dataframe

library(data.table)
 setDT(FinalData)[, as.list(colSums(.SD)), by = gl(ceiling(420/5), 5, 420)]

this gives me:

Error in colSums(.SD) : 'x' must be numeric

```
and 

library(dplyr)
 FinalData %>%
   group_by(indx = gl(ceiling(420/5), 5, 420)) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum))

which gives me error: 
Error in Summary.factor(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

  Site.Date.Plot  CarA  CarB    CarC...
1.SL.VI.1          0     0        1
2.SL.VI.1          0     0        0
3.SL.VI.1          0     6        0
4.SL.VI.1          0     0        3
5.SL.VI.1          1     0        0
...
every 5 rows has a different $Site.Date.Plot. I expect this:

  Site.Date.Plot  CarA  CarB    CarC...
1. SL.VI.1          1     6       4
2. SL.VI.2         ...   ...      ...

But I get the above error messages from above.
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Could you provide a sample of data so we can see the situation? Take a look at [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Calum, I provided a small portion of my data in my post, should I post more than that? Do you need my whole datasheet?

Comment: It's better to use ```dput``` so people can copy and paste. Also, including 20ish rows may have been better just to verify that every 5 rows there is a different Site.Date.Plot. So, ```dput(FinalData[1:20, 1:4])``` would have been great.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
FinalData %>%
   group_by(Site.Date.Plot) %>% 
   summarise_all(list(sum))
```

This will preserve the first column and sum the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `mutate_at` if you want to keep the first column `Site.Date.Plot`

```
library(dplyr)

FinalData %>%
  group_by(indx = gl(ceiling(420/5), 5, 420)) %>%
  mutate_at(2:37, sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Or it will also work with `summarise_at` but you'll loose the first column in this case

```
FinalData %>%
  group_by(indx = gl(ceiling(420/5), 5, 420)) %>%
  summarise_at(-1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: mutate_at definitely worked. Is there a way I can get the output as a new dataframe and not just in the console? Many thanks.

Comment: just assign it to an object. `new_data <- FinalData %>%
  group_by(indx = gl(ceiling(420/5), 5, 420)) %>%
  mutate_at(2:37, sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1)`

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that in your `data.table` and `dplyr` solutions, the `sum` function is operating on the factor of `Site.Date.Plot`. That's why you are receiving the error.

The second improvement is that your factor `Site.Date.Plot` changes every 5 rows. In other words, we can simply group by that instead of creating a different index.

These solutions are untested since there isn't enough sample data.

```
library(tidyverse)

 FinalData %>%
   group_by(Site.Date.Plot) %>%
   summarise_all(sum)

library(data.table)

setDT(FinalData)
FinalData[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = 'Site.Date.Plot']

#base R
aggregate(x = FinalData[, -1], by = list(FinalData$Site.Date.Plot), FUN = sum)
```